# using an array to subset an array in Swift4

Tags: arrays, swift4

This must be a really basic question. In languages like R you can take an array (swift syntax here)

```
let x = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and extract multiple elements using an array of indices. That is I would like to be able to do something like say (now in a pseudo-Swift syntax because it does not parse)

```
x[[0,2,3]]
```

to get a return value of

```
[1,3,4]
```

but this does not work directly in Swift. Is there a standard way of doing this? I am currently using Swift4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything built into the Swift `Array` class that does this.

One possible solution is to define an extension to `Array` that filters the array to only include the elements at the provided indices.

```
extension Array {
    func elements(at indices: [Int]) -> Array<Element> {
        return self.enumerated().filter { indices.contains($0.0) }.map { $0.1 }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let x = [1,2,3,4,5]
let res = x.elements(at: [0,2,3])
print(res)
```

Output:

> [1, 3, 4]

Comment: that works and makes perfect sense. Many thanks, David